, I am trying to install micro python on thonny to write code for my Raspberry Pico 2 board
I am trying to install micro python on Thonny ide so I can do coding with my Raspberry Pico 2 board but I keep getting error code.
The error is this ( File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Thonny\lib\urllib\request.py", line 496, in _call_chain
result = func(*args)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Thonny\lib\urllib\request.py", line 643, in http_error_default
raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found).this.
I have tried going to the web address and it says the same error 404. I hope this is the right place to post sorry has I am new to this.
Hope you can help.
Thank you in advance.
I dropped boot file on Pico first.
then made selections then pressed install.

Per the following GitHub issue:
https://github.com/thonny/thonny/issues/2913
and through some deduction, I think you need to change the link value in here
https://github.com/thonny/thonny/blob/master/data/rpi-pico-firmware.json
which seems to be the file that Thonny uses to download the appropriate firmware.
So basically: download the source from the GitHub repo, change the link to the appropriate one on the website for downloading MicroPython (https://micropython.org/download/RPI_PICO2/), and then setup Thonny from source and it should be fixed.
I am having the same issue and will get down to fixing it right now, hopefully the above will provide you with some useful information.

Do I need to change the address in Thonny if so where in the program do I put the new address for downloading micropython sorry I am new to this
